# redirect all routes to https in nuxt project hosted in heroku

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, heroku, nuxt.js

I'm trying to create a middleware to redirect all my routes to https, I think I need a middleware so I've created a `redirect.js` file in the middleware folder of Nuxt and then I've added this to `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
router: {
  middleware: ["redirect"]
},
```

And here is my `redirect.js` file that gives me a server error:

```js
export default function({ app }) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   if (app.context.req.header("x-forwarded-proto") !== "https") {
  app.context.res.redirect(`https://${app.context.req.header("host")}${app.context.req.url}`);
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I found an easier way i've added the package redirect-ssl

```
npm i redirect-ssl
```

and then i've added this line in my nuxt.config.js :

```
serverMiddleware: ["redirect-ssl"],
```

Comment: Try this line if you want to enable it only for production: `import redirectSSL from 'redirect-ssl'; export default { serverMiddleware: [redirectSSL.create({enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'})]}`

Comment: @AlbertiBuonarroti i have exactly this copied from https://github.com/nuxt-contrib/redirect-ssl#using-with-nuxtjs but it does not redirect on my Heroku deploy. I have NODE_ENV set to "production" in heroku config vars.

Comment: I spent half a day solving this issue and only this solution fixed the SSL issue.

Comment: just super - thanks...

Answer (score 2):

For nuxt 3 (it works with heroku):

```
import redirectSSL from 'redirect-ssl'
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const protocol = event.node.req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']; // http || https
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV; // development || production
  if (protocol === 'http' && env === 'production') {
    return redirectSSL(event.node.req, event.node.res)
  }
})
```

Comment: In which file did you add this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this in heroku.

For Nuxt static mode:

1. Add the https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git buildpack *after* the heroku/nodejs buildpack under buildpacks
2. Make sure the buildpacks are added in this order to an `app.json` in the root directory of your project
3. Add a `static.json` in the root directory of your project

   - Make sure `root` and `https_only` are set correctly
   - If you want Nuxt to resolve routes instead of Nginx (so that you don't get the Nginx 404 page when you go to an unknown route), set `routes` as well.

Example static.json:

```
{
  "root": "dist/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  },
  "https_only": true
}
```